# Shall I remove "I am" in the second sentence if two sentences are connected by "and" in the middle?

Tags: conjunction-reduction

> I am a student at State University and  I am pursuing a Master Degree.

or

> I am a student at State University and  pursuing a Master Degree.

Which one is correct?

Comment: *Even fun*... remove 'and' as well! :)

Comment: I don't know whether you can say "a Master Degree" in US English, but in British English, it's "a Master's degree" with **'s** after "Master".  I think this would be the more usual form in the US as well.

Answer (score 1):

*"I am a student"* is the simple present tense.

*"I am pursuing a Master Degree"* is the present progressive tense.

So you can't omit *"I am"* in the second part, because it would be a simple sentence with one subject and compound predicate (see [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3DGKY3eM9PY&feature=youtu.be)). And [here](https://www.ecenglish.com/learnenglish/lessons/using-parallel-verbs) you can find the rule for those sentences:

> Remember: when the subject of a sentence does two or more things, the
>   verbs use the same tense.

But if you don't omit *"I am"* you get a correct compound sentence with two independent parts. So, the correct phrase is *"I am a student at State University and I am pursuing a Master Degree"*.